# which protocol is being used for publishing

Tags: content-delivery, publishing

How to find out what protocol is being used for publishing to the presentation server?

We have a file server (for content reposotory) and a webserver which hosts the sites. I checked deployer and broker. In broker the file server location is mentioned but how to be sure of the protocol?

Comment: It does a FTP to the deployer, then in broker i see the "file server" location (publicationdefaultroot)..Please suggest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The protocol of deployment is setup in the Publication Target on the CMS, this is done under Destinations in the General tab of the Publication Target.

The configuration of the Deployer is just specifying where to pick the transport packages up from, unless it is a HTTP/HTTPS Deployer, then the protocol is depending on the setup of the website (either HTTP or HTTPS).

So when you use a Local File System protocol or FTP, the Deployer configuration is basically the same, but the Publication target will have a different protocol in its destination.

The configuration of the Broker is completely separate and has nothing to do with the deployment of Transport Packages. The locations specified in the Broker configuration are where the files will eventually end up after deployment is done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It does a FTP to the deployer, then in broker config, i see the "file server" location (publicationdefaultroot).Is there any way to find out which protocol it uses to connect to the file server mentioned in the broker config? Please suggest

Comment: Broker config: Publications DefaultRootLocation="//file server/Repository" DefaultRootDataLocation="//file server/Repository/data" /> , just for your reference.

Comment: The broker doesn't use any "protocol" to get to the storage location, it uses standard FileSystem IO.